# Mockito... how to handle a method that creates a new object from an existing one

Tags: android, mockito

I have a class with a method which constructs a new object based on the value of an object passed to it.

e.g. Simplified version, hope there's no typos

```
public class MyLocation extends Location {
...
public MyLocation move(double speed, double dir, int seconds) {
    return new MyLocation(getLatitude() + cos(dir)*speed*time, getLongitude() + sin(dir)*speed*time);
}
}
```

But I get errors from the setters and getters in the Location constructor.

```
Method setTime in android.location.Location not mocked
```

Given there's more than one attribute being calculated, I need to return an object that contains them, which will need to be constructed. But since this is a newly constructed object, there's no way to Mock it, unless I put @Mock in the actual code, which I know is a Bad Idea.

I really don't understand why Mock is applied to other classes like Location that I'm not trying to test. Just give me the object back so I can verify that the calculations were correct.

Surely this isn't an uncommon scenario, yet it looks like I'm the only person running into it! Am I stuck in some kind of antiPattern?

I've been round and round in circles on this one, with different constructors, subclasses and static methods and all kinds of groovy things, but I'm just missing the illumination to get me out of this maze.

Comment: Why do you mock `Location`? It looks like a data class and it's probably easier/simpler to simply `new` up a real instance with the required values to be used by the test.

Comment: That's the whole problem... I don't want to mock Location.  I mock a MyLocation, but then the constructor (or elsewhere) calls to Location setters crash out with the Method is not mocked" error.

Comment: Why do you mock `MyLocation`? It still looks like a data class. Can't you use a real `MyLocation` instance, properly set up through the constructor?